# Exception on library in Tomcat Apache web application no TLDs found

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I just started learning Apache Tomcat and I just even recently Installed it, Am trying to run a particular Java program/class that waits/listens for data from a php post request and below is the code. I call this class `Listener.java`

```
 package matchfaces;

 public class Listener {

        public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT = "1699";//8080
        static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner =
        php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

        public static void main() {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {
            System.loadLibrary("facesdk");
            int res = FSDK
                            .ActivateLibrary("LICENCE KEY");
            FSDK.Initialize();
            FSDK.SetFaceDetectionParameters(true, true, 384);
            FSDK.SetFaceDetectionThreshold(5);

            if (res == FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
                    System.out.println("FaceSDK activated\n");
            } else {
                     System.out.println("Error activating FaceSDK: " + res + "\n");
            }
    } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
             System.out.println("exception " + e.getMessage());
    }

    runner.waitFor();
}
```

}

After much research I tried a couple of things but now, it seems the libraries I need are not being load and thus throwing an exception. My `web.xml` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Match Faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>matchfaces.Listener</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Match Faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/matchfaces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>ViewHandler.handler</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So I used a listener so On Tomcat start server it would fire the web application java class `Listener.java`

```
public class handler implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
     try {
         Listener listen = new Listener();
         listen.main();
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Listener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


 }
```

The error I get is this

> exception no facesdk in java.library.path

Comment: What are you trying to create? A JSF application? A servlet? You don't really know?

Comment: @Kayaman what I wanted to achieve is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478878/connecting-php-and-java-via-a-javabridge-port-in-openshift) in that link. so it lead me to tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem you are having is fron the `System.loadLibrary("facesdk");` It seems you have not provided a path to the `facesdk.dll` library. But rather than state the path in the `loadLibrary` method just head to your `catalina.bat` file and right under `:noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%` add this `set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=%CATALINA_BASE%\lib"`
This should work just fine.